# Python, i have a file with the datetime format and i can't transfer it

Tags: python, shutil

this is my file: **2023-02-05 014715.166977_logs.txt**

I see i have problem with symbol  and idk how to fix it :/

code Python: `file = str(datetime.now())`

When i use print():
**2023-02-05 01:47:15.166977**

How do I transfer a file:

```
shutil.move()
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? Include the error traceback to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
file = str(datetime.now())
file.replace(":","-")
```